# "Stand to" or "stand"? As a meaning of tolerating

Tags: word-usage

First of all, I'm really sorry for my bad English.
I was watching the use of 'stand' as a meaning of tolerating, bearing
So I made a sentence like this

• It is really hard to stand to not meet him.

I think, 'To not meet him' is incorrect maybe? 
I cannot sure, maybe the whole structure is wrong too

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *to not meet him*. Rephrasing the sentence (which also changes the meaning), I'd more expect to hear: *I can't stand his absence* or just *It's difficult to be without him.* Or, more precisely, *It's difficult to think of not  meeting him* or *It's difficult to make myself not meet him.* Typically, we say *I can't stand* rather than *It's hard to stand*. If we do say *hard to stand* it's often in a larger phrase like *it's hard to* ***stand firm*** *(in the face of something)*. So, even though your sentence is correct, it's a little unusual.

Comment: It might help if you explained what you intend the sentence to mean.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answer  helped me a lot! I had better say like the first one :) thank you so much

Comment: And my intention was right this "It's difficult to think of not meeting him" exactly what I wanted to say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words in English that can take a sentential complement (whether they are verbs, nouns, or adjectives) often limit what kind of complement they can take. (I mention this to emphasise that there is not a grammatical rule that matters here, just the requirements of the particular word - here "stand" - which just have to be learnt.)

*Stand* meaning *tolerate* can take either a gerund ('*-ing*') clause, or a 'to'-infinitive clause. To my own (British English) ear, the 'to'-clause sounds odd, and I would always use the gerund "I can't stand not meeting him". But the GloWbE corpus, a little to my surprise, shows the two forms occurring about equally. The UK part of the corpus shows *-ing* about twice as common as *to*, which suggest that it *is* partly about different varieties of English.